# How many characters have Haoshoku: King's haki

Tags: one-piece

How many characters have Haoshoku: King's haki, can any one please list it out.
Till 2016 please

Comment: Please 'define' current season. In a year 'current season' can have a whole different meaning from now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic due to a lack of effort on the OP's side.

Comment: What Dimitri mx meant is that one can just google the terms Haoshoku: King's haki and click on the first result that returns: http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Haoshoku_Haki_Users

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Boa Hancock
- Chinjao
- Donquixote Doflamingo
- Edward Newgate
- Monkey D. Luffy
- Naguri (filler/non-canon)
- Portgas D. Ace
- Shanks
- Silvers Rayleigh

Source: http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Haki/Haoshoku_Haki.

Comment: You forgot Dragon and old man Gol D. Roger

Comment: Sorry for Roger. But Dragon is not certain.

Comment: @Sorin Lascu Roger and Dragon unexplained.